# Error creating Android Debug.Keystore on Windows 10

Tags: android, windows, delphi

I am trying to create android debug.keystore for my google map api.

Here's my script at command line:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

I also verified the following before running:

- keytool.exe exists inside the folder — C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin
- .android folder exists my user's name folder — C:\Users\my_user_name\.android

And finally, here's what I get:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\dennisbullo\.android\debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\dennisbullo\.android\debug.keystore
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:742)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:340)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:333)
```

I have read a lot of documentation and honestly, it looks like my case is different or simply I missed something.

Comment: You used the `-list` command which shows the content of an *existing* keystore. The specified keystore doesn't exist so the command fails.

Comment: @Olivier I tried without the -list but I am still getting the error — Usage error: no command provided

Comment: If you don't specify a command, of course it will fail. You should read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html).